# Merge a nested array of objects by overall key (without lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nuxt.js

I have a set of objects (product data) that I have sorted from an API - the objects contain repeat keys and repeat arrays of information as a product can have many categories and subcategories.

```
{
   "category":"e-liquid",
   "subcategories":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"50ml",
            "id":19
         }
      },
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"100ml",
            "id":18
         }
      },
   ],
}

{
   "category":"e-liquid",
   "subcategories":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"50ml",
            "id":19
         }
      },
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"100ml",
            "id":18
         }
      },
   ],
}

{
   "category":"e-liquid",
   "subcategories":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"50ml",
            "id":19
         }
      }
   ]
}

{
   "category":"hardware",
   "subcategories":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"tanks",
            "id":15
         }
      }
   ]
}

{
   "category":"hardware",
   "subcategories":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"tanks",
            "id":15
         }
      },
      {
         "attributes":{
            "name":"coils",
            "id":14
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Each JSON object above represents an individual product.

I want to be able to merge/reduce all subcategories uniquely by their category key i.e. e-liquid, hardware or whatever else gets thrown at it into a singular flat object or array, one for each category I suppose. Something like:

```
{
   "category":"e-liquid",
   "subcategories":[
      "50ml",
      "100ml",
      "150ml",
      "200ml",
      "...anything else"
   ]
}

{
   "category": "hardware",
   "subcategories":[
      "coils",
      "tanks",
      "batteries",
      "...whatever else"
   ]
}
```

Any insight is appreciated. Been searching stackoverflow for a while but nothing seems to have cropped up - already tried a few solutions from similarly worded questions, but often merges were too shallow, and I can't wrap my head around how I would deep merge (assuming that's what's needed here). My lodash isn't working in my nuxt config hence why I specifically am asking for non-lodash solutions if possible.

Comment: In your input, the first object has attributes as an object. In the last one, attributes is a string. Was that intentional?

Comment: @AndrewParks thanks for pointing this out, I have corrected now, it was not intentional, attributes is an object all across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the unique category names, then get unique attribute names for each of those categories:

```js
const data = [{"category":"e-liquid","subcategories":[{"attributes":{"name":"50ml","id":19}},{"attributes":{"name":"100ml","id":18}}]},{"category":"e-liquid","subcategories":[{"attributes":{"name":"50ml","id":19}},{"attributes":{"name":"100ml","id":18}}]},{"category":"e-liquid","subcategories":[{"attributes":{"name":"50ml","id":19}}]},{"category":"hardware","subcategories":[{"attributes":"tanks","id":15}]},{"category":"hardware","subcategories":[{"attributes":"tanks","id":15},{"attributes":"coils","id":14}]}];

const r = [...new Set(data.map(i=>i.category))].map(i=>({
  category:i,
  subcategories:[...new Set(data.filter(({category:c})=>c===i)
    .flatMap(({subcategories:s})=>s.map(({attributes:a})=>a.name??a)))]
}));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: This solution seems succinct kudos my man, just going to try implement it now - I need to practice getting my head around maps and filters. By the looks of it, this will take whatever categories and subcategories get thrown at it and sort correct? i.e. if another category came along with it's own subcats. Generally however, a product will only have one category and many subcategories. I will reenforce this on my side.

Comment: @logikurl yes it should accommodate as many categories as you need. Btw, if attributes is always an object, you can change  `=>a.name??a` to just `=>a.name`

Comment: Worked like a charm, is short, sharp and reasonably readable. Marking as answer thank you so much Andrew. This has helped me greatly. I have renamed to`a.name` as yes attributes will always be an object, but really sharp eye and great input.

Comment: quick question - is there a way to flatten the subcategories array further, so instead of subcategories: [ [ ] ] it's subcategories: []

Comment: @logikurl oops, my answer had extra square brackets in it. it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

Learn more about [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set?retiredLocale=en)

```js
const obj = [{ "category":"e-liquid", "subcategories":[ { "attributes":{ "name":"50ml", "id":19 } }, { "attributes":{ "name":"100ml", "id":18 } }, ], }, { "category":"e-liquid", "subcategories":[ { "attributes":{ "name":"50ml", "id":19 } }, { "attributes":{ "name":"100ml", "id":18 } }, ], }, { "category":"e-liquid", "subcategories":[ { "attributes":{ "name":"50ml", "id":19 } } ] }, { "category":"hardware", "subcategories":[ { "attributes":"tanks", "id":15 } ] }, { "category":"hardware", "subcategories":[ { "attributes":"tanks", "id":15 }, { "attributes":"coils", "id":14 }]}];

const subCat = item => item.map(it => it.attributes.name || it.attributes);
const res = obj.reduce((a, {category, subcategories}) => {
if (a[category]) return {...a, [category]: {category, subcategories: [...new Set([...a[category].subcategories, ...subCat(subcategories)])]}}

return {...a, [category]: {category, subcategories: [...new Set([...subCat(subcategories)])]}};
},{});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works great, but the usage of `Set` is more succint and readable.

Answer (score 0):

We can group the objects by category by building an object with categories at its keys. The simplification of subcategories is a little trickier, since the structure of subcategory objects differs by category.

In the snippet below, I've introduced `subCatValue`, an object whose values are functions that specify how to get the salient subcategory value for a given category.

The `reduce` groups by category and does the subcategory combination in one trip through the array. A second trip cleans up duplicate subcategories.

```js
const data = theAPIdata();

const subCatValue = {
  'e-liquid': obj => obj.attributes.name,
  'hardware': obj => obj.attributes
}

const index = data.reduce((acc, product) => {
  acc[product.category] ??= { category: product.category, subcategories: [] };
  // subCatValue[product.category] is a function that plucks the value we need
  // mapping it over the subcategory array produces an array of salient values
  const values = product.subcategories.map(subCatValue[product.category]);
  acc[product.category].subcategories.push(...values)  
  return acc;
}, {});

const values = Object.values(index);

// go through again, removing duplicate subcategories
values.forEach(v => {
  v.subcategories = Array.from(new Set(v.subcategories))
});

console.log(values);

function theAPIdata() {
  return [{
      "category": "e-liquid",
      "subcategories": [{
          "attributes": {
            "name": "50ml",
            "id": 19
          }
        },
        {
          "attributes": {
            "name": "100ml",
            "id": 18
          }
        },
      ],
    },

    {
      "category": "e-liquid",
      "subcategories": [{
          "attributes": {
            "name": "50ml",
            "id": 19
          }
        },
        {
          "attributes": {
            "name": "100ml",
            "id": 18
          }
        },
      ],
    },

    {
      "category": "e-liquid",
      "subcategories": [{
        "attributes": {
          "name": "50ml",
          "id": 19
        }
      }]
    },

    {
      "category": "hardware",
      "subcategories": [{
        "attributes": "tanks",
        "id": 15
      }]
    },

    {
      "category": "hardware",
      "subcategories": [{
          "attributes": "tanks",
          "id": 15
        },
        {
          "attributes": "coils",
          "id": 14
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works, but I need it to take whatever categories and subcategories come from the results API. Having a hardcoded `const subCatValue` doesn't seem like it would work.

Comment: @logikurl - happy you got it working. As I noted in the answer, the main problem the answer grappled with was handling the inconsistency in the shape of the data between categories, an issue you erase with your edit to the data in the OP

Comment: Thanks Dan. Yes that was a typo on my part my apologies, a very sharp eye and great workaround for the data inconsistency. Luckily, an API that returns inconsistent data is not on the books as that would be nightmare fuel!